# how to skip newline /n or sentences that don't make sense?

Tags: nlp, spacy, data-cleaning

I have used spacy to tokenize and to try and get some word stats from a subset of text but it also prints new lines \n and short sentences or ones that don't make sense. How do I get rid of these?

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
def describe_sentence_stats(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    sent_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for i, sent in enumerate(doc.sents):
        sent_df.loc[i, 'sentence'] = sent.text
        sent_df.loc[i, 'num_words'] = len([token for token in sent])
                                          
    return sent_df

sentences = describe_sentence_stats(example_text)
```

I would like to get rid of these types of outputs:

[image: Some of the output]

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of garbage in, garbage out. Based on your output your input has a section like this:

```
l
i i
1 i
1 i i i i i
```

That's pretty weird. You should pre-process your text before giving it to spaCy, by removing lines that are too short, or have < 5 different characters, or where the number of spaces is 50% of the number of characters, etc.

When you give text to spaCy, it treats the input as inviolable, and it never throws any part of it away. As a result even "weird garbage" like those lines has to be in some sentence and appear as tokens.

Sometimes it can be easier to filter stuff like that in spaCy itself, but it's often easier to do it in a prior step. In your example, since the problem text seems to be in isolated lines, I would definitely recommend you give preprocessing a try.